# Conditional row count in cassandra using hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

How can i do a conditional row count in cassandra using hector  something like below we do in RDBMS using hector thrift API:

Select count(*) from table_name where column_name = column_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of count query statement is not possible in cassandra. To achieve the same you can use Cassandra Counter Family

Comment: Take the example of stackoverflow site. Suppose i have to count the number of answer of a particular question , how can i do that:  iterate over the rows of column family or shall i maintain a counter family to count the number of answer

Comment: you should maintain a CF for that. Moreover its a cost effective way

Comment: can you suggest a effective way for this.

Comment: best practice will be update your cassandra counter column family counters while data is getting inserted.